# Global Search Auto-Complete in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, global-search

I am trying to configure the auto-complete items show by the global search bar.
In my org an account search result is only shown as `[Account Name] Account`. Some opportunities are shown as `[Opportunity Name] Opportunity [Account Name]` but others are just shown as `[Opportunity Name] Opportunity` even though there's an account assigned to the opportunity.

The screenshot below illustrates the behaviour:

[image: Global search auto-complete results]

My questions regarding this component:

1. Why are some records (of the same object type [Opp.]) displayed differently? There are no record types for opportunities set up
2. Is it possible to configure the fields shown here (in particular I want to display the account site or billing city within the result to differentiate between different sites of the same company)?

Thanks!